# How can I ensure that the validator and nominator do not incur transaction fees?

Tags: substrate-node-template, validator, transaction-fees, nominator

I would like to prevent the fees mechanism within the chain from imposing any transaction fees on validators and nominations. Could someone kindly provide guidance on achieving this?

Comment: does this solve your question ? https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/b09ab37119acf0f3c4c8b9e3662255afd6d0ae53/substrate/frame/support/src/dispatch.rs#L116

Comment: No. I want to implement the no fees for the validator only. Not for all the users